# Do there exist any products that provide USB-C to DisplayPort with USB Power Delivery?

Tags: macbook-pro, hdmi, displayport, usb

There's no way to connect a display over DisplayPort (to get 4K@60Hz, whereas all the abundant HDMI-having docks/adapters/hubs would operate at HDMI 1.4 limiting to 4k@30Hz) while charging the laptop at the same time.

Looking for a product that supplies passthrough power while NOT converting to an HDMI signal.

Answer (score 2):

Here's [USB C to DisplayPort with PD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0746NM5H9). Hope you've found it already!

Comment: Don't know who downvoted this, very helpful for me with a similar problem!

Answer (score 1):

Usb type c to display port adaptors with 4k 60Hz resolution are available on the market.

In order to get a 4k 60Hz resolution output on the display port side your usb-c port must support Display Port alt mode. Laptops that have this type of usb-c ports are MacBook, ChromeBook Pixel™ and Dell™ XPS™ models 15 and 13.
When the usb-c port does not support the Display Port Alt mode then the max resolution is limited (mostly to 1080p) regardless of an extra power supply for the adaptor.

Comment: You did not address my question which is about usb-c displayport alt mode alongside USB PD (power delivery).

Comment: You're simply expanding on what I already explained about DP alt mode. Which is appreciated. But is not an answer.